# Set an ion-option with dynamic values

Tags: angular, ionic2

how can we make an `<ion-select >` (ionic v2) with dynamic values (ion-option).

the vaules should be token from a json object as shown below .

```
    {  
   "direction":[  
      {  
         "idd":"1",
         "villedepart":"kasserine",
         "villearrive":"sfax",
         "ligne_direction":"kasserine sfax"
      },
      {  
         "idd":"6",
         "villedepart":"sousse",
         "villearrive":"tunis",
         "ligne_direction":"sousse tunis"
      },
      {  
         "idd":"9",
         "villedepart":"nabeul",
         "villearrive":"sousse",
         "ligne_direction":"nabeul sousse"
      }
   ],
   "success":1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can simply be done with having your json stored in a variable, here e.g `values`. Then you iterate through `values.direction` and display which property you want, here `villedepart`:

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Values</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let val of values.direction">{{val.villedepart}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/QQVQU2puDxO75M9gzpeK?p=preview)

Check [**this link**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/) for ionic select.

You can optionally when you get your data extract the array directly from the response, which means that you can iterate the values directly:

Service:

```ts
getData() {
  return this.http.get('url')
    .map(res => res.json().direction) // this here!
}
```

Component:

```ts
this.myService.getData()
  .subscribe(data => {
     this.values = data;
  });
```

and then iterate like so:

```ts
<ion-option *ngFor="let val of values">{{val.villedepart}}</ion-option>
```

Comment: thinks a lot  #AJT_82